# Validation rule on phone number field

Tags: validation-rule

When I make a validation rule on phone number field that the phone number field should only contains number and only 10 digits allowed, but when making new records the phone number field is required, how I avoid it

Comment: Have you tried this? `AND(
   NOT(ISBLANK(Phone)),
   REGEX(Phone, "^[0-9]{10}")
)`

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This isn't a place to get your work done for free, so you need to [edit] your question to show us what you've tried and point to a specific thing that you're having trouble with.

Comment: It works thanks

Answer (score 0):

Validation Rule Formula:

```
AND(    
    NOT(ISBLANK(Phone)),    
    REGEX(Phone, "^[0-9]{10}")
 )
```

[ISBLANK](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isblank.htm&type=5) function checks whether the field value is blank or not and the [NOT](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_not.htm&type=5) function returns FALSE for TRUE and TRUE for FALSE.

[REGEX](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5) function compares a text field to a regular expression and returns TRUE if there is a match. Otherwise, it returns FALSE.